# Примонтировать ntfs-диск в небезопасном состоянии

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint, dual-boot, ntfs

> Error mounting /dev/sda9 at /media/qwertiy/Data E: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda9" "/media/qwertiy/Data E"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
>   Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda9': Operation not permitted
>   The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>   Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Насколько я понимаю, это предупреждение предназначено для предотвращения проблем с записью на диск при несброшенном кэше, например, в случае гибернации Windows.

1. Действительно ли имеет смысл загрузка в Windows в случае, если перезагрузка производилась при помощи reset? Если нет, то как проигнорировать ошибку?
2. Как примонтировать диск в readony-режиме?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation шикарный ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Вот, почитайте, тут все подробно описано:
https://losst.ru/montirovanie-razdela-windows-v-linux

Comment: @SeryiBANANAN, во-первых, ссылки надо писать в комментариях, а не в ответах. Ну либо переносить основную часть в сам ответ. Во-вторых, приведённая статья хотя и по теме, вопрос вообще не решает. Там говорится, что диск сам примонтируется в readonly-режиме, а в вопросе ошибка аналогичная, но вместо фоллбека происходи отказ монтирования - возможно, за прошеднее время схему монтирования улучшили до описанной в статье, а может это из-за другого дистрибутива.

Comment: @Во-вторых, приведённая статья хотя и по теме, вопрос вообще не решает@ - Файл гибернации, который вызывает тут проблему, и описан в статье? Нет  конечно, не слышали, мы же первым делом удаляем ответы

Comment: @Windows cache@ - Файл гибернации? Нет, не слышали, мы же не думаем сами

Comment: @SeryiBANANAN, я знаю, что такое файл гибернации. Более того, когда я задавал вопрос, гибернация использовалась мной намеренно. Хотя и не в тот момент, когда был задан вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) да, иногда перезагрузка в виндоуз и выключение помогают :-)

2) маунтим нтфс в ридонли в `~/user/temp/ntfsro`

```
sudo mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb5" "/home/user/temp/ntfsro"
```

параметры и пути меняйте как вам угодно

`/dev/sdb5` - сами понимаете, раздел с Windows

uid/guid 1000 - дефолтный айди юзера под убунтой (и, наверное, дебианом и минтом)

**Про гибернацию:**

очень хороший [ответ](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/536939)/статья, Вкратце - если у тебя память сброшена на диск, а потом делаешь какие-нибудь изменения в ФС, возможно, Вин может  свалиться при перезагрузке.

Если затронешь что-нибудь важное, можно в принципе, потерять данные (поскольку система восстановится в память, предполагая, что все находится на месте).

Т.е. винда приводит ФС, память, запущенные программы в консистентное состояние после перезагрузки из гибернации

**Про резет:**

При резете у тебя все равно будет dirty bit выставлен для ФС, поскольку при резете она может повредиться, и винда в этом случае прогонит свой аналог fsck и снимет dirty bit при нормальной перезарузке.

Если ты в Linux в  RW режиме начнешь писать в битый NTFS, нет никакой гарантии, что не сломаешь вообще все (лично мне неизвестно, какие проверки делает ntfs-драйвер в линуксе), я бы перестраховался.

Наверное можно замаунтить форсом, но зачем?  Это только в каких-то экстремальных случаях требуется. Лучше перезагрузиться.

Comment: 1. Да, помогают. Но если там не гибернация, а нажатие reset, то имеет ли перезагрузка хоть какой-то смысл?

Comment: Да, именно так. Поэтому и вопрос, делает ли при этом винда что-то полезное, или же просто чистит флаг? А по каким словам искать статью? Может ссылку приведёшь?

Comment: перенес комментарии в ответ

Comment: Кстати, винда сама решает, запускать ли chkdsk. И ей крайне редко хочется запустить его для всех дисков. В большинстве случаев он вообще не запускается, иногда запускается для одного-двух. Словить для всех - это очень редкое исключение. Хотя от десятки пару раз видел недавно.

Comment: ну тут все зависит, в каком состоянии журнал находился, думаю. там же чуть ли не транзакции) видимо по этому и определяет - запускать или нет